# Ember js use of variable from controller to hbs file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, ember-data

I am new to `emberjs`. I have a button , I want to disable that button on the basis of some value. I have a two controllers, I am calling a method from controller A which is of controller B. So, That I can use that variable in the `hbs` file. So, my code is like -

**controller A-**

```
App.controllerA = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ['searchResult'],
  isrequestFromApplicationVar: undefined,

  actions: {
    isrequestFromApplication: function() {
      isrequestFromApplicationVar = true;
      console.log("======================>" +isrequestFromApplicationVar);
    },

    SetisrequestFromApplication: function() {
      isrequestFromApplicationVar = null;
      console.log("in the else xof the function====>" +isrequestFromApplicationVar);
    },
  }
}
```

**controller B**

```
App.controllerB = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  needs:['controllerA'],

  actions: {
    searchvalue: function(query) {
      var self = this; // use this inside ajax request
      var value =  location.search.split('userName=')[1];

      if(value) {
        this.get('controllers.controllerA').send('isrequestFromApplication');
      } else {
        this.get('controllers.controllerA').send('SetisrequestFromApplication');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So, from here I am able to call the methods as well.

```
<button class="btn btn-success" {{action "moveToCorpus"}} {{bind-attr disabled=isrequestFromApplicationVar}}>Move To corpus</button>
```

This is my `hbs` file content, I want to disable this button. So, I am not able to use that value in the hbs file ? can any one please help me with this?

Comment: which ember version ? Are you learning or working on old project?

Comment: Working on a old project

Comment: Use set method instead of `isrequestFromApplicationVar = true;`  this should be written as `this.set('isrequestFromApplicationVar', true)`;

Comment: Yes I was doing the same thing but it is giving me the error."Assertion Failed: Cannot delegate set('isrequestFromApplicationVar', true) to the 'content' property of object proxy <App.controllerA:ember368>: its 'content' is undefined."

Comment: Which version exactly are you using ? - `ObjectController` and `ArrayController` and `needs` deprecated in latest version. I haven't worked with old version.

Comment: ember": ">= 1.0.0"

Comment: you can consider using the ember-cli. Sorry I am not aware of ObjectController and ArrayController

Comment: Now I am able to set the property, Now that value is not reflecting in the hbs file

Comment: I defined property to false and the this.set and then used that in the same way in hbs file but that value is not reflecting, It remains false

Comment: Which hbs file you are including ,you can update question with your current code.

Comment: updated the code

Comment: What is template name ? is it context of the controllerA or controllerB ?. I think context is wrong.  You include modified code in js to for others to understand well.

Comment: So, It is the context of  controller  A and  added the code from the template

Comment: try introducing the one property like `name:'Ember'` and use it in template ? confirm is it showing properly. if it's so then the problem is `disabled` atrribute behavour. ie., if you got `disabled` attribute then its disabled and if you don't have it then it's enabled. its not respecting true/false value

Comment: To confirm this value is reflecting or not, you can display `isrequestFromApplicationVar` in text field or in span

Comment: I used the property in the hbs file it is showing that value.

Comment: okay then `disabled` attribute behaviour in html is the problem

Comment: I did the <p>property</p> , So, that value which I defined as a default is showing but not the updated ones , Its not updating

Comment: above comment you said its working !!. any how this is wrong `<p>property</p>` it should `<p>{{isrequestFromApplicationVar }}</p>`

Comment: Problem is that the value is not becoming true, even if  condition is true

Comment: No, the property value is not chaning. I mean I  am not getting any error now, this.set('isrequestFromApplicationVar', true); after doing this , but this true value not getting assigned to the isrequestFromApplicationVar

Comment: Please create working jsfiddle only then its possible to understand the real problem. Its very very old ember version.